# New to php. retrieve information from array

Tags: php, json

Hey guys im trying to retrieve information from this array.

```
Array
(
    [userid] => 1
    [username] => dunkers
    [password] => 699e5fae54df4c82314e42dd86c4d383
    [email] => a.dunkerley7462@student.leedsb
)
Array
(
    [userid] => 2
    [username] => mantis
    [password] => 699e5fae54df4c82314e42dd86c4d383
    [email] => ad481993@hotmail.com
)
Array
(
    [userid] => 190
    [username] => helenanderson94
    [password] => 699e5fae54df4c82314e42dd86c4d383
    [email] => helenandersonnn@hotmail.co.uk
)
Array
(
    [userid] => 191
    [username] => dd
    [password] => 699e5fae54df4c82314e42dd86c4d383
    [email] => dd@dd.com
)
```

Im trying to makea for each loop which only picks out the values of the username and ive been researching for hours and everyway i try it it come up with illegal string etc

```
 foreach($encodedResults as $row){

    $decode = json_decode($row, true);

    print_r($decode);
```

this is just some starter code which i made just to pull all the information out of the array but again i just want the values of username

Comment: within the foreach, `echo $decode['username'];`

Comment: Google "PHP associative arrays" for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
foreach($encodedResults as $row){
    $decode = json_decode($row, true);
    echo $decode['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great job getting them to output, here is an example of echoing just the username.

```
// Loop through JSON encoded entries
foreach($encodedResults as $row)
{
    // Decode result to an array
    $decode = json_decode($row, true);

    // Echo out the username key in the decode array.
    echo $decode['username'];
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions!